# ActiveJob Serialization: no call to deserialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, rspec, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I'm trying to implement the fairly straightforward example from [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Core.html#method-i-deserialize) which overrides ActiveJobs' serialize et deserialize methods to save an attempt_number integer between job retries.

I have tried implementing the example into my project, on RAILS 4.2.7.1, which results in the following:

- A job class that is very bare bone and uses an 'active_elastic_job' queue

  ```
  class Job < ActiveJob::Base
    queue_as :a_queue

    def serialize
      super.merge('attempt_number' => (@attempt_number || 0) + 1)
    end

    def deserialize(job_data)
      super
      @attempt_number = job_data['attempt_number']
    end

    rescue_from(Exceptions::NetworkError) do |error|
      logger.info "#{error}"
      if @attempt_number > 10
        logger.info "Drop"
      else
        logger.info "Attempt #{@attempt_number}"
        retry_job wait: 1.hour
      end
    end

    def perform(id)
       ...
    end
  end
  ```
- A Model that uses the Job on after_create

  ```
  class Model
    after_create do
      Job.perform_later(self.id)
    end
  end
  ```
- And finally a RSpec test aimed to trigger a retry through Webmock

  ```
  RSpec.describe CategorizerJob, type: :job do
    include ActiveJob::TestHelper

    # Some let calls for url, json and create

    context 'retry ctx' do

     it '404' do
       stub_request(:get, url).to_return(body: json, status: 404)

       perform_enqueued_jobs do
         expect_any_instance_of(Job)
         .to receive(:retry_job).with(wait: 1.hour)
         create()
       end
     end

  end
  ```

Now here is the issue, it seems the deserialize methods never gets called as I've tried adding a binding.pry in it but to no avail.
All I get is the below issue when running RSpec which I assume is cause by the missing call to deserialize:

```
    Failure/Error: if @attempt_number > 10

         NoMethodError:
          undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

Anyone could help me with that ? If even with an alternative way to achieve similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and found out that the method you should override on the ActiveJob::Base subclass is `deserialize_arguments`. Here is a stack trace when executing the job:

```
activejob-4.2.8/lib/active_job/arguments.rb:42:in `deserialize'
activejob-4.2.8/lib/active_job/core.rb:90:in `deserialize_arguments'
activejob-4.2.8/lib/active_job/core.rb:80:in `deserialize_arguments_if_needed'     
activejob-4.2.8/lib/active_job/execution.rb:30:in `perform_now'                    
activejob-4.2.8/lib/active_job/execution.rb:21:in `execute'
```

Althought the example in the docs states otherwise, `deserialize` is defined in `ActiveJob::Arguments`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call this

```
ActiveJob::Arguments.deserialize(arguments)
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a NetworkError exception. I think you should see connection options of adapter and find why it occurs.

Comment: The NetworkError exception is normal. As I said, the rspec aim to trigger the retry in rescue_from by answering with a 404, which throws the exception. Now I know i shouldn't retry on 404, it is just an example. Furthermore where I need help is in the serialisation which for some reason doesn't deserialise meaning I get a nil object when doing "if @attempt_number > 10" hence the error.

Comment: you can read more about serialization and deserialization in ActiveJob here:


https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2016/09/25/decoding-rails-magic-how-does-activejob-work